# discretize function of multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, apriori

I have the following csv: 
https://github.com/antonio1695/Python/blob/master/nearBPO/facturasprueba.csv

With it I want to use the `apriori` function to find association rules. However, I get the error:

> Error in asMethod(object) : 
>   column(s) 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 not logical or a factor. Discretize the columns first.

I have already bumped into this error before, and what I did was:

```
dataframe$columnX <- discretize(df$columnX)
```

However, this only works if I select manually each column and discretize them one by one. I would like to do the same thing but for aprox 3k columns. The case I gave you has only 11, I'm guessing that 11 will do.

Comment: would `dataframe <- sapply(dataframe, discretize)` work?

Comment: No, i got the following error:     * Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L,  : 
  ‘min’ not meaningful for factors*

Comment: I'm not sure but it might be because the first column isn't a numerical column. @Warner

Comment: I made the first column an index, I'm not sure how it would affect the apriori function. It doesn't seem to crash until I used the apriori function. It sends me the following error:         Error in asMethod(object) : 
  matrix is not logical or a numeric 0-1 matrix!             @Warner

Comment: I wonder if `dataframe[,2:12] <- sapply(dataframe[,2:12], discretize)` would work in this specific case. If it does, then it is just detecting those columns that are not logical nor a factor and using that vector of column indices.

Comment: Sorry it took long I went to eat. I did it and it kinda discretized it, however when I run apriori it says it still isn't discrete! @aichao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, thanks for everyones help though. To select and discretize multiple columns:

```
for (i in 2:12){df[,i]<-discretize(df[,i])}
```

Comment: Why didn't `dataframe[,2:12] <- sapply(dataframe[,2:12], discretize)` work? Your approach may be slower for large number of columns that need to be discretized.

Comment: I tried to do it and when I used apriori it still said that they weren't discrete!

Comment: Error in asMethod(object) : 
  column(s) 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 not logical or a factor. Discretize the columns first.

          That's the error I got afterwards. @aichao

Comment: If you found how it works properly I can gladly take my answer down. As you said it does take much more than your function! @aichao

Comment: Hey, if it works for you, then it works! I was just curious because I thought the two should be functionally equivalent.

Comment: Me too, I just don't know why. And I honestly would appreciate a better solution since mine isn't efficient and I'm gonna be working with 4k columns...

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz does it discretize by frequency or interval?